# Convertir el formato de la fecha a YYYY-MM-DD y este se devuelva en formato DATE

Tags: sql, plsql

Obtengo un campo fecha y por defecto esta en dd-mm-yyyy.NO puedo devolver la fecha con formato CHAR. Tampoco puedo usar Session. Alguien tiene otra idea?. (con TO_CHAR me cambia la fecha al formato deseado, luego uso TO_DATE para convertilo a DATE, Pero este establece el valor por defecto y vuelve al formato original que es DD-MM-YYYY). La consulta esta en un store procedure y este devuelve los datos en un cursor. El store es llamado por un servicio. Gracias.

Comment: convertirlo en donde y para usarlo en donde y como?

Comment: ¿que lenguaje estás usando?

Comment: En una consulta de un registro de una tabla, que uno de sus campo es fecha_creacion y este se devuelve en un cursor.

Comment: Estoy usando PLSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo el siguiente ejemplo muestra cómo convertir el formato de fecha en diferentes formatos.

Para el formato japonés:

```
select CONVERT(nvarchar(30),getdate(), 111) as Japanformat
```

Para formato de EE. UU:

```
select CONVERT(nvarchar(30),getdate(), 110) as USAformat
```

Para formato ANSI:

```
select CONVERT(nvarchar(30),getdate(), 102) as ANSIformat
```

Para formato británico:

```
select CONVERT(nvarchar(30),getdate(), 103) as Britishformat
```

Para formato alemán:

```
    
select CONVERT(nvarchar(30),getdate(), 104) as Germanformat
```

Para formato italiano:

```
select CONVERT(nvarchar(30),getdate(), 105) as Italianformat
```

Para el formato predeterminado europeo:

```
select CONVERT(nvarchar(30),getdate(), 113) as EuropeDefaultformat
```

Para ODBC Canonical:

```
select CONVERT(nvarchar(30),getdate(), 120) as ODBCCanonicalformat
```

Es importante mencionar que usted Siempre tiene la opción de usar la función FORMATO para obtener la fecha en el formato que desee:

```
SELECT FORMAT( getdate(), 'dd/MM/yy')
```

En FORMATO es más fácil de manejar fechas y usar el formato que prefiera, ya que no necesita conocer el estilo. Sin embargo, en mi experiencia veo mucho código usando las funciones CAST y CONVERT, así que es mejor conocerlas.

> De SQLShack.com

Answer (score 0):

*Obtengo un campo fecha y por defecto esta en dd-mm-yyyy...*

Si el campo es de tipo **Date** entonces lo que estas viendo a través de Toad, SQL Developer, SQL PLUS, Squirrel o lo que sea que uses para conectarte a la base de datos solo es una representación para que la puedas ver en la pantalla pero siempre es un **Date**, por dentro no tiene formato, es tu herramienta la que te lo muestra con el formato con el que el creador de la herramienta puso para visualizar este tipo de dato.

*con TO_CHAR me cambia la fecha al formato deseado, luego uso TO_DATE para convertilo a DATE Pero este establece el valor por defecto y vuelve al formato original que es DD-MM-YYYY*

Aquí tu herramienta ve que otra vez que tienes un **Date** y por eso te lo muestra como la herramienta sabe mostrar los **Date**.

Es como por ejemplo: Con Squirrel los numeros de mis tablas me los muestra con separador de miles. Pero no están guardados con separador de miles es la herramienta la que me los muestra así. Si veo la misma tabla desde SQL Developer los veo sin separador de miles.

Por eso en los Sistemas Informáticos las fechas y los números se formatean con algún formato que indica el usuario, si pide que las fechas se muestren separadas con guiones: DD-MM-YYYY  se programa la pantalla para que aplique el formato a la fecha que viene de la Base de Datos, si luego pide que las fechas se muestren en formato YYYY/MM/DD se aplica el formato en la pantalla es solo un tema de presentación.

Comment: pero si yo devuelvo el campo con la fecha convertida mediante el to_char en un cursor. Se enviara como si fuera un string y no un campo tipo Date.

Comment: Es verdad. Yo no he dicho lo contrario. A lo mejor es necesario aclarar más el problema. ¿La consulta esta en un store? ¿Quien invoca a la consulta un programa?

Comment: Quiero que se devuelva la fecha con el formato date. Si la consulta esta en un store procedure. El store es llamado por un servicio.

Comment: Estimado como bien te comento Alvaro, no existe el formato date, es la representación que haces en la aplicación la cuál ocupa un formato, de hecho el date internamente es un número, si quieres obtener el valor con formato lo debes enviar como string y sino aplica el formato luego en su aplicación.